# Как пишется «экоГТО»?

Tags: раздельно-дефис, слитно-дефис, аббревиатуры, слитно-раздельно-дефис

ЭкоГТО. Как же люди извращаются, придумывая такие словечки.
Как правильно писать в данном случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Промчимся по словарям:
[ГТО](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%93%D0%A2%D0%9E) [гэтэо] — *нескл., с.* и *неизм.* (значок ГТО, нормы ГТО) (*сокр.: готов к труду и обороне*);
[эко...](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE) — первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно (экосистема, экофорум, экоэнергетика).

Посмотрим в ПАС (под ред. Лопатина):

> [§ 206.](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=94#pp94) В приставочных, сложных словах и составных наименованиях, характеризующихся слитным или дефисным написанием, буквенные и звуковые аббревиатуры сохраняют прописные буквы, напр.: *суперЭВМ, мини-ЭВМ, микроГЭС, МГД-генератор, УКВ-передатчик*...

Сделаем вывод: **экоГТО** (слитно, со строчной буквы), нормы экоГТО, эстафета для школьников «ЭкоГТО» (если название, то в кавычках и с прописной буквы).

Answer (score 3):

По всей видимости, так и писать: ***экоГТО***.

**эко…** – *первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно* ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE*&all=x))

> [**Вопрос № 284663**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=284663)
>
> Как пишутся аббревиатуры с приставками, например псевдоСМИ?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Приведенное Вами написание правильно. Ср. также: *антиНАТО, квазиНИИ, микроЭВМ, телеКВН, спецПТУ.*